# How to get out of recovery mode even though iPhone doesn't appear to be in recovery?

Tags: ios

My phone doesn't show any signs of being in recovery mode but when I plug it into my PC, it says that iTunes cannot connect because it is "Recovery Mode". I tried to hold the sleep button and home button until the Apple logo shows but nothing is happening.

Comment: Try holding past the Apple logo as shown in [this post](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201263). It should bring you to recovery screen, then let go and press and hold the power and home button until the Apple logo comes back up. This will enable, then disable Recovery mode.